# IDENTITY_INSERT in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to turn it on in a table trigger?

I tried creating a trigger with 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName ON

But when I open the trigger definition, I see that the statement is not there....

This is my query to alter my trigger to add the IDENTITY_INSERT, when I open the definition, the IDENTITY_INSERT is removed ...

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTrigger]
ON [dbo].[MyTable]
AFTER INSERT AS



INSERT INTO MyOtherTable
(   
    // values
)


SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable OFF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn it on and off in the trigger, your SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON needs to be here :

AFTER INSERT AS

**SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable ON**

INSERT INTO MyOtherTable

rather than before the trigger definition begins. In its current location it's only on when the trigger is being created, not when it's actually being utilised.

Comment: do you know what permission I have to set to the sql account to be able to execute that IDENTITY_INSERT statement

Comment: The user will need ALTER TABLE permission on the relevant table.

Comment: I suggest you use the EXECUTE AS option within the trigger to reduce the potential vulnerability.